# How to get data column separated in foreach loop

Tags: php, codeigniter, for-loop, foreach, while-loop

How to get data in different section like today, upcoming, and overdue date with the help of foreach loop.

```
foreach($list as $index=>$row) {                                 
    $dueDt = new DateTime($row->due_timeDate);
    $todayDt = new DateTime('now');
    $due = $dueDt->format('Y-m-d');   
    $today = $todayDt->format('Y-m-d');  

    if($due == $today) {                               

        echo $due.' Today' ;
        echo '<br>';
        $task['today'][]=$row;

    } elseif($due>$today) {

        echo $due.' Upcoming'; 
        echo '<br>'; 
        $task['today'][]=$row;

    } elseif($due<$today) {

        echo $due.' Overdue';; 
        echo '<br>';   
        $task['overdue'][]=$row;
    } 
}
```

My data is coming like this:

```
2015-10-30 Upcoming
2015-10-29 Today
2015-10-28 Overdue
2015-10-28 Overdue
2015-10-27 Overdue
2015-10-27 Overdue
2015-10-15 Overdue
```

But I want the data like this from foreach loop:

```
Upcoming
        2015-10-30 

Today
        2015-10-29 
Overdue
        2015-10-28 
        2015-10-28 
        2015-10-27 
        2015-10-27 
        2015-10-15
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$task['today'] = array();
$task['Upcoming'] = array();
$task['Overdue'] = array();

foreach ($list as $index => $row)
{
    $dueDt = new DateTime($row->due_timeDate);
    $todayDt = new DateTime('now');
    $due = $dueDt->format('Y-m-d');
    $today = $todayDt->format('Y-m-d');
    if ($due == $today)
    {
        $task['today'][] = $row;
    }
    elseif ($due > $today)
    {
        $task['Upcoming'][] = $row;
    }
    elseif ($due < $today)
    {
        $task['Overdue'][] = $row;
    }
}
foreach ($tasks as $dueDate => $task)
{
    if (!empty($task))
    {
        echo $dueDate . "<br />";

        foreach ($task as $date)
        {
            echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" . $date . "<br />";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use key value pairs of your array.

Take key as time (Today, Tomorrow, Overdue).

This should be a multi-dimensional array.

Print in loop like following:

```
<?php
$tasks = array();
foreach($list as $index=>$row) {
  $dueDt = new DateTime($row->due_timeDate);
  $todayDt = new DateTime('now');
  $due=$dueDt->format('Y-m-d');
  $today=$todayDt->format('Y-m-d');
  if($due==$today) {
    $tasks['today'][] = $due;
  }
  else if($due>$today) {
    $tasks['upcoming'][]=$due;
  }
  else if($due<$today) {
    $tasks['overdue'][]=$due;
  }
}
if (! empty($tasks)) {
  foreach ($tasks as $dueDate => $task) {
    echo ucwords($dueDate);
    if (! empty($task)) {
      foreach ($task as $title) {
        echo "<br/>--> " . $title;;
      } 
    }   
  }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
foreach($list as $index=>$row) { 

    $dueDt = new DateTime($row->due_timeDate);
    $todayDt = new DateTime('now');
    $due=$dueDt->format('Y-m-d');   
    $today=$todayDt->format('Y-m-d');  

    if($due==$today){

        $up['upcome']=$row;

    }elseif($due>$today){

        $to['Today']=$row;

    }elseif($due<$today){

        $over['overdue']=$row;
    }

    if (!empty($up)) {
        echo "Upcoming";
      foreach ($up as $new_up) {
        echo "&nbsp;" . $new_up['upcome']."<br>";  
      }
    }
    if (!empty($to)) {
        echo "Today";
      foreach ($to as $new_to) {
        echo "&nbsp;" . $new_to['Today']."<br>";  
      }
    }
    if (!empty($over)) {
        echo "Overdue";
      foreach ($over as $new_over) {
        echo "&nbsp;" . $new_over['overdue']."<br>";  
      }
    }
}
```

**Output will be**

```
Upcoming
        2015-10-30 

Today
        2015-10-29 
Overdue
        2015-10-28 
        2015-10-28 
        2015-10-27 
        2015-10-27 
        2015-10-15
```

Comment: @Amit  did you check this??

Answer (score 0):

According to your data-structure:

```
$data = ['2015-10-25','2015-10-26','2015-10-27','2015-10-28','2015-10-29','2015-10-30'];
$current = '2015-10-27';

// Saving Array Keys for future work
$rows = array('overdue','today','upcomming');

foreach($data as $date) {
    // Compare each date to find our $rows array
        $curt = strtotime($current);
        $d = strtotime($date);
        if($d < $curt) {
            $rows['overdue'][] = $date;
        } else if($d > $curt) {
            $rows['upcomming'][] = $date;
        } else if($d == $curt) {
            $rows['today'][] = $date;
        }
    }

//Now Print each $rows:
echo 'Overdue: <br>'. implode('<br>', $rows['overdue']) .'<br><br>';
echo 'Today: <br>'. implode('<br>', $rows['today']) .'<br><br>';
echo 'Upcomming: <br>'. implode('<br>', $rows['upcomming']);
```

**Prints:**

```
Overdue: 
2015-10-25
2015-10-26

Today: 
2015-10-27

Upcomming: 
2015-10-28
2015-10-29
2015-10-30
```